# Text highlighting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

I have a text in the following format:

```
<div id="text">
  <div>Hello world</div>
  <div>How are you</div>
</div>
```

User selects the "w" of world:

So I get the selection and can insert the span:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var startNode = $(selection.anchorNode.parentElement);
var endNode = $(selection.focusNode.parentElement);
var startIndex = startNode.index();
var endIndex = endNode.index();
var startOffset = selection.anchorOffset;
var endOffset = selection.focusOffset;
```

Result:

```
<div id="test">
  <div>Hello <span class="id1">w</span>orld</div>
  <div>How are you</div>
</div>

id1.startNode = 0
id1.endNode = 0
id1.startOffset = 6
id1.endOffset = 7
```

The user user now selects "d Ho" of the text. This is how it should look like:

```
<div id="test">
  <div>Hello <span class="id1">w</span>orl<span class="id2">d</span></div>
  <div><span class="id2">Ho</span>w are you</div>
</div>

id2.startNode = 0
id2.endNode = 1
id2.startOffset = 9
id2.endOffset = 2
```

But using the method from before `selection.anchorOffset` yields me the index relative to the new created text nodes which are now "Hello ", "w" and "orld" which means I get an index of 3 instead of 10.

I use the following code to get the offset that was created:

```
var offs = 0;
if(startNode.context.innerHTML.length > startNode.context.innerText.length) {
    var n = startNode.context.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        if(n[i].textContent === selection.anchorNode.textContent) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            offs += n[i].textContent.length;
        }
    }
}
console.log(offs);
```

I can now add the offset to the start and end but this kind of breaks when the selection goes over different nodes or contains a selection inside of it. I also have no idea how to generate the spans with those offsets. There are also way to many cases that I have to consider like startNode === endNode or if a selection contains a span fully or partly.

Are there any common approaches or frameworks for stuff like this? I would rather just work with pure text indices instead of html tags inside and let something else handle the proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of self-promotion, my [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) library has a [Class Applier module](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Class-Applier-Module) specifically for this.